# Collect CPU load average from ESXI 5.1 via SNMP

Tags: cpu-usage, snmp, esxi

Does anyone know if there is an OID I can use to get the average CPU load from an esxi 5.1 machine? (UCD-SNMP-MIB::laLoad is not available)

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/VMWARE-RESOURCES-MIB.php MIB file to monitor ESXI 5.1 via SNMP

Comment: This MIB does not seem to have the metric I need: the cpu load average for the past 5 mins. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you check cpuTable ? It should contain CPU utilization information.

Comment: snmpwalk -u <user> -v3 <host> 1.3.6.1.4.1.6876.3.1.2
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.6876.3.1.2 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
The esx node does not know of this MIB